# What is the difference between a regular foreach and ForEach LINQ operator when it comes to async/await

Tags: c#, linq, asynchronous, foreach, async-await

Here are three versions of same(?) functionality

Version 1:

```
public async Task SomeMethodAsync(List<string> foos)
{
    foreach(var foo in foos)
    {
        await SomeOtherMethodAsync();
    }
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Version 2:

```
public void SomeMethod(List<string> foos)
{
    foos.ForEach(async foo => await SomeOtherMethodAsync());
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Version 3:

```
public async Task SomeMethod(List<string> foos)
{
    var tasks = foos.Select(foo => SomeOtherMethodAsync());
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

1. Why does this first version require the method to be marked async to use await inside the foreach loop vs the second version which doesn't need to be marked async (just the Lambda needs to be async).
2. Does the second version wait for all the async/await calls inside the loop to complete before SomeMethod exits? I ask this because SomeMethod() is not async and it will not be awaited by it's caller.
3. Is the third version the preferred way over versions 1 & 2?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is pretty broad, especially since it's got more than one question in it. But, in the interest of helping…

> 1. Why does this first version require the method to be marked async to use await inside the foreach loop vs the second version which doesn't need to be marked async (just the Lambda needs to be async).

A method must be marked `async` to use `await`. In your second version, the outer method doesn't use `await`. Only the anonymous method declared within does. That anonymous method is an entirely different scope, and the use of `await` within it does not involve any actual changes to the outer method. They are effectively two completely independent method declarations in that respect.

> 2. Does the second version wait for all the async/await calls inside the loop to complete before SomeMethod exits? I ask this because SomeMethod() is not async and it will not be awaited by it's caller.

The second version is not legal code. There is no `IList<T>.ForEach()` method. I'm assuming your real code uses `List<T>.ForEach()`. With that in mind…

No. Your second version starts all of the async operations and then returns. This should've been clear when you observed the code running.

> 3. Is the third version the preferred way over versions 1 & 2?

The third version is not legal code. It should not be marked `async`. But, assuming your real code is correct and does not have such a method marked as `async`…

"Preferred" is a matter of opinion. However, given that only the third version both runs all of the operations concurrently *and* provides a mechanism for waiting for them all to complete, it certainly seems the most *useful* of the three.

> 4. Is it just with the ForEach LINQ operator or does the same thing happen with other LINQ operators such as Where, Select etc?

(There is no *"ForEach LINQ operator"*…see above.)

Does the *"the same thing"* happen? That would depend entirely on how you use them. You already have an example (your third one) that uses `Select()`, and which works differently. So in that sense, obviously *"the same thing"* does not happen. But it's the same in the sense that all of the asynchronous operations get started together and the enumeration can complete before those operations complete.

On the other hand, the `ForEach()` method is synchronous and immediate, while LINQ methods use deferred execution. That is, they create an enumeration object, but the actual enumeration does not occur until you actual use that object.

So in your second example, the operations are all started by the time the `ForEach()` method returns. But in the third example, they don't start until you call `WaitAll()` and that method enumerates the projection you created with `Select()`.

The phrase *"the same thing"* is not well-defined and could mean a variety of things. As you can see, it's *"the same"* in some ways, and not *"the same"* in other ways.

Comment: I see how the 4th part of the question is ambiguous. I removed it as I could not find a better way to word it.

Comment: so if the second version just kicks of the async operations and returns then what's the point of using `await` inside that? Is there ever any good reason to use that? Should I always prefer regular foreach loop over List.Foreach()?

Comment: _"Changed the third version to use await"_ -- IMHO it would have been better to remove the `async`. The `await` is only really useful when there is more code executed in the method after it. A method where there is only one `await` and it's the last thing in the method, you should just return the `Task` that's being awaited, without `async`.

Comment: _"so if the second version just kicks of the async operations and returns then what's the point of using await inside that?"_ -- none. This is a variation on what I'm describing in my previous comment; you have a method, there is only one `await` and it's the last thing that happens...you might as well just return the `await`ed `Task` instead. _"Is there ever any good reason to use that?"_ -- not in my opinion, not for that specific scenario that is. (Using `await` in an async lambda can be useful, as long as there's something else in the lambda after the `await`.)

Comment: _"Should I always prefer regular foreach loop over List.Foreach()"_ -- that's a matter of opinion, and one which has nothing to do with the `async`/`await` pattern. That is, it's my opinion that `foreach` is almost always preferable, but only because for me, it's more readable. Whether it's preferable in your example depends on what your goals are. ...

Comment: ... Per above, the two don't actually do the same thing when the `ForEach()` delegate is an `async` method and when you _do_ `await` in the `foreach` loop. But that has more to do with the specific example than whether `foreach` is _generally_ more preferable to `ForEach()`.

Comment: to keep the examples simple I did not have anything after that. I changed the code samples to show that there is more work to be done after the foreach.